# Expo React Native quando clico para abrir o modal, o expo reinicia fechando o app

Tags: react, react-native, modal, expo

Pessoal peço a ajuda de você, quando clico no meu modal o expo simplesmente reinicia o app, vou postar o codigo!

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Image, TextInput, Modal, Alert, Linking, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import SwipeableRow from '../../Linhas/Usuarios';
import api from '../../../services/api';
import url from '../../../services/url';
import { styles } from './styles';
import { showMessage, hideMessage } from "react-native-flash-message";
import { EvilIcons, MaterialIcons, AntDesign, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

interface DadosProps {
data: {
id: string;
nome: string;
usuario: string;
senha: string;
nivel:string;
foto: string;
}
}

const CardUsuarios = ({ data }: DadosProps) => {

```
const [abrirModal, setAbrirModal] = useState(false);
const navigation: any = useNavigation();


async function excluir(nome:string, id:string) {

    Alert.alert('Sair', `Você tem certeza que deseja excluir o Registro : ` + nome, [
        {
            text: 'Não',
            style: 'cancel',
        },

        {
            text: 'Sim',
            onPress: async () => {
                try {
                    const response = await api.get(`apiConexao/usuarios/excluir.php?id=${id}`);

                    showMessage({
                        message: "Excluído Sucesso",
                        description: "Registro Excluído",
                        type: "info",
                        duration: 800,
                    });

                    navigation.push('Usuarios');
                } catch (error) {
                    Alert.alert('Não foi possivel excluir, tente novamente!')
                }
            }
        }
    ])
}
    
  
return (
    <>
        {data.id === undefined && data.nome === undefined ?
           
           <Text style={{ color: '#595858', fontSize: 14, marginTop:10, alignContent:"center", textAlign:"center" }}>Nenhum Registro Encontrado!</Text>
            
            :

            <View>
                 <SwipeableRow
                    onPressWhatsapp={async () => {
                        await Linking.openURL(`http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=55${data.nome}`)
                    }}

                    onPressEdit={async () => {
                        navigation.push('NovoUsuario', { id_reg: data.id });
                    }}

                    onPressDelete={async () => {
                        excluir(data.nome, data.id);
                    }}

                  
                >                   
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.box}
                        onPress={() => setAbrirModal(true)}
                        
                    >     
                         <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', marginTop:-5}}>                       
                         <View style={{width:65}}>
                         <Image style={{width:60, height:60, marginTop: 18}} source={{uri:(url + 'apiConexao/Homem.png')}} />
                          </View>
                          <View style={{ width: '100%', marginTop: 4, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize:15}}>Nome: {data.nome}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize:15 }}>Usuário: {data.usuario}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize:15 }}>Nivel: {data.nivel}</Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize:15 }}>Senha: {data.senha}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                             

                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    </SwipeableRow>
               
            </View>
        }
```

<Modal
visible={abrirModal}
animationType={'fade'}
transparent={true}
onRequestClose={() => {
setAbrirModal(!abrirModal)
}}

```
  >
      <View style={styles.centralizarModal}>
     <View style={styles.CardContainerModal}>
     <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.removeItem}
          onPress={() => setAbrirModal(false)}
        >
          <EvilIcons name="close" size={25} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
     <Text style={styles.Cliente}>{data.nome} - {data.nivel}</Text>
            

            <View style={styles.Section}>
                <MaterialIcons style={styles.Icon} name="people-outline" size={22} color="#c1c1c1" />
                                  
            </View>              
        

           
            <View style={styles.Section}>
                <MaterialIcons style={styles.Icon} name="mail" size={22} color="#c1c1c1" />
                <Text style={styles.Entrada}>Usuario: {data.usuario}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.Entrada}>Senha: {data.senha}</Text>
            </View>              


            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url + 'painel/images/perfil/' + data.foto)}>
                        {(() => {
                            if (data.foto != 'Homem.png' && data.foto != '' && data.foto != null) {

                                return (
                                    <View style={styles.viewImg}>
                                        <Image style={styles.ImagemModal} source={{ uri: (url + 'painel/images/perfil/' + data.foto) }} />
                                        <Text style={styles.textoAbrir}>(Clique para Abrir)</Text>
                                    </View>
                                )

                            }

                        })()}
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                                            

         </View>
         </View>
      </Modal>



    </>
);
```

}

export default CardUsuarios;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quando clico nesse card ele chama o modal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O modal abre e o expo reinicia

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
e volta para a tela inicial

Answer (score -2):

Tenta fazer ele abrir primeiro o Modal sem nenhum conteúdo, isso pode te ajudar a entender o que tá sendo executado e causando o problema. Tente tambem deixar funções async await fora do escopo do alert, pode ocorrer do alert esta executando a função sem você chamar.